# How control milliseconds precision when using ISO8601?

Tags: c#, datetime, format

I am using the following:

```
var data = DateTimeOffset.Now.ToString("O");
```

the variable 'data' contains this:

```
2023-09-12T08:53:57.9285767-05:00`
```

The issue I have is that I must provide the milliseconds with 3 digits maximum:

```
2023-09-12T08:53:57.928-05:00`
```

Is there a way to format the date using `.ToString("O")`? I searched the web and the only thing I found was to use something like this:

```
var data = DateTimeOffset.Now.ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'.'fffK");
```

Is this the only way?

Comment: Net library only has a limited number of standard datetime format.  When using a non-standard format you have to use your solution.  See following for complete list of standard formats : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to format the date using .ToString("O")?

No, [The round-trip ("`O`", "`o`") format specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings#Roundtrip) is a static format.

No matter what [`CultureInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo) you use, it always generate `yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'.'fffffffK` formatted string. As you can see, there *always* will be 7 digit for millisecond part.

The code you provided as;

```
var data = DateTimeOffset.Now.ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'.'fffK");
```

is the **correct** way to generate 3 digit milliseconds. This is called "custom date and time format specifiers".

See: [The "`fff`" custom format specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#fffSpecifier)